# restore notes iCloud IMAP

Tags: icloud, notes.app, imap

I've deleted "notes" IMAP folder. Now I have no notes on Macbook, iPhone, iPad.
Please help me to restore my notes. I have TimeMachine backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restoring ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes (I would keep a copy of the existing folder in case this causes other problems). That's where my Notes seem to be stored. If that doesn't work, you can dig out the individual files representing your Notes within that folder.

The directory structure of the com.apple.Notes folder is very odd. It seems to have aliases to things like my Desktop and Movies folders in it, for reasons that I completely do not understand. In any case, I found my IMAP Notes in ~Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/CoreData/ExternalRecords/E7804A95-977C-4A1C-98A1-8C1D77E02D49/IMAPNote/_records/0/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But after restoring, when I connect to the internet, all restored notes disappearing again :(

Comment: Hm. So I think you're going to have to copy and paste the text into new notes. You should just be able to open the relevant files from the Finder.